# How to delay an execution in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code where a big sensitive object is created and the execution is better to be triggered later as possible.

```
    public MyObject MyExecution(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
    {
      return new MyObject(p1,p2,p3,p4);
    ]

    public LongTimeAfter(Invokable<MyObject> invk)
    {
      MyObject obj = invk.Invoke();
    }

    public void main(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
    {
      Invokable<MyObject> invk = new Invokable<MyObject>(new Func<MyObject,P1,P2,P3,P4>(MyExecution), p1, p2, p3, p4);
      LongTimeAfter(invk);
    }

    class Invokable<T> 
    {
        private Func<T,P1,P2,P3,P4> _f; 
        private P1 _p1;
        private P2 _p2;
        private P3 _p3
        private P4 _p4;

        public Invokable<T>(Func<T,P1,P2,P3,P4> f, P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
        {
          _f = f;
          _p1 = p1;
          _p2  = p2;
          _p3 = p3;
          _p4 = p4;
        }

        public T Invoke()
        {
          return _f(_p1, _p2, _p3, _p4);
        }
    }
```

I know that in Functional programming where variable and not declared it is possible.

Is this possible in c#? Why not or how please.

Comment: Is this asynchronous in some way?  Otherwise the code isn't going to continue until the operation is complete anyway.  I guess it's not clear to me what the problem being solved here is.

Comment: Why later? Why not now? If nothing else, move the work to a parallel thread, but I don't see any reason to artificially delay the execution.

Comment: You can use `Lazy<T>` to run code only when needed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For example if MyObject is a shared read write Stream in another machine

Comment: how do you determine *that* specific point of time? fixed duration? some condition?

Comment: I need some conditions to be met or more accurately the flow to reach `LongTimeAfter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone in the future:

```
public MyObject MyExecution(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
  return new MyObject(p1,p2,p3,p4);
]

public LongTimeAfter(Func<MyObject> invk)
{
  MyObject obj = invk();
}

public void Main(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
  Func<MyObject> invk = () => { return MyExecution(p1, p2, p3, p4);};
  LongTimeAfter(invk);
}
```

The lambda expression only wraps the execution. 
This way it can be both delayed and encapsulated the real function and parameters from `LongTimeAfter()`.

Although it is not the best practice it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple threads involve? if no and all flow goes synchronous (in one thread only), it should not cause the problem you are saying.

and if It is asynchronous, you can use "Events and Delegates",
However following approach is best when we are dealing with multiple classes.

It would be like,

```
public delegate void LongTimeAfterEventHandler(Func<MyObject>);

public event LongTimeAfterEventHandler LongTimeAfterEventTriggred;

public MyObject MyExecution(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
   //Assuming that object of "MyObject" is needed to pass only in "LongTimeAfter" method
  if(LongTimeAfterEventTriggred != null)
      LongTimeAfterEventTriggred(new Invokable<MyObject>(new MyObject(p1,p2,p3,p4)));
}

public LongTimeAfter(Func<MyObject> invk)
{
  MyObject obj = invk.Invoke();
}

public void Main(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
  this.LongTimeAfterEventTriggred += LongTimeAfter;
  MyExecution(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really simple for you to just do this:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int> f = () => MyExecution(1, 2, 3, 4);

    //some time later
    int result = f();
}

public int MyExecution(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
{
    return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a timer or a another thread.sleep(mseconeds).

Comment: I don't know how much time to wait.